# POST with JSON has intermitent WebAPI resolution issue

Tags: angularjs, json, firefox, asp.net-web-api

This error has perplexed me. I have been working on this application for a year now and one of the most original parts of it just started failing for no apparent reason. I haven't made any configuration changes or changes in and around the area which is failing, so it is baffling me.

**Requirement**

In my SPA, click on a button and the JSON model associated to that button is sent to the server to be saved.

**Implementation**

```
return $resource('/api/audits/:auditId/auditAnswers', { auditId: auditId, auditAnswer: auditAnswer }).save(auditAnswer);
```

This in turn is handled by WebAPI 2.0

```
[Route("api/audits/{auditId}/auditAnswers")]
[HttpPost]
public ServiceResult SaveAuditAnswerByAudit(HttpRequestMessage request, Guid auditId, [FromBody]AuditAnswerModel auditAnswer)
{ ... }
```

**Issue**

This worked for a good year without issue. Now when I test in Firefox 46.0.1 hosted in IIS Express, only about 1 in 5 attempts actually reaches the WebAPI method. No other post seems to reach WebAPI at all.

The error occurs as soon as I attempt the post, so it does not seem like it's timing out, either.

**Firefox reports**

```
Accept      application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate
Accept-Language     en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length      348
Content-Type        application/json;charset=utf-8
Host        localhost:61032
Referer     http://localhost:61032/QAT/Audits/f3fa490d-6324-4227-b8fa-a6be4d33dd82
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
```

Also, no HTTP status code is reported.

The error Callback for $resource is called and the response object contains:

```
data       null
status     0
statusText ""
```

I have come across this once already and fixed it by not posting the entire JSON to WebAPI, but there are times I need to do this and consider it the correct way to do so.

Thinking it may be browser related I have restarted the browser, computer, cleared cached, and none of these methods resolved the issue. However, using a different browser such as Chrome does not encounter this issue (yet).

The fact that it works "eventually" (after about 5 attempt) is most concerning to me.

**Question**

Is this a known issue? Is it my fault? Is there something I can do to fix it?

Comment: What is the HTTP status code you're getting back from the call? You left that out of your "Firefox reports" section.

Comment: @CraigW. when it fails I don't get any status code back at all...

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If it's hitting the web server you should be getting *something* back. Have you tried using an HTTP proxy like Fiddler to watch the request/response traffic?

Comment: @CraigW. Amazing... when I run Fiddler, it always works. When I close Fiddler the issue resumes. I think it must be something environmental going on...

Comment: Still would be nice to know what is causing this and how to resolve it